# Is it Possible to export the Analysis Services DB from SSMS into Visual Studio as we can do in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: ssms, ssas-tabular, ssdt-2017

I have created a cube on SSAS in Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) and deployed on SQL Server Analysis server. I can see the deployed the Analysis Server DB on Prod in SSMS. Over a period of change, I created multiple version of that DB and I can't find the deployed DB in the history of visual studio. Now I need the deployed DB which I can see in SSMS. My objective is to re-open the deployed Analysis Server DB in Visual Studio. I hope I am clear in putting the things rightly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4457/create-project-from-a-deployed-ssas-tabular-database/):

> Open the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), and select the menu option
> "File" > "New" > "Project". Select Import from Server (Tabular) option
> as shown below and click OK.
> [image: Import from server]